# If for &*x both * and & are not evaluated, then why not have the same rule for *&x?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, evaluation, unary-operator

C2x, 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators, Semantics, 3:

> The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type "type", the result has type "pointer to type". If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue.

If for `&*x` both `*` and `&` are not evaluated, then why not have the same rule for `*&x`? I.e. the same rule for the unary `*` operator.

Comment: I suspect the rule for `&*x` enables some optimization, but I cannot pin it down at the moment. Consider that `*&x` always “works”: Given any lvalue or function designator, `&` produces its address and `*` produces the original lvalue or function designator. So a rule that they are not evaluated would not change anything. However, for `&*x`, the `*x` part by itself could dereference a null, misaligned, or otherwise invalid pointer. The rule that neither is evaluated means the compiler can ignore these possibilities…

Comment: … However, the compiler can already ignore these possibilities, since the behavior of `*x` when `x` is a null pointer, misaligned, or an invalid pointer is already not defined, so the compiler would be free to treat `&*x` as `x` anyway. So this is not the explanation, but I suspect there may be something along these lines.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Re: "the compiler can already ignore these possibilities": it does (GCC, Clang): after `*x` the `if(x == NULL)` is replaced by `if(0)`, and later removed.

Comment: Re: "it does (GCC, Clang)": ICC as well. MSVC doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Because the value may change, reference not.

```
int foo(volatile int x)
{
    return *&x;
}


int *bar(volatile int *x)
{
    return &*x;
}
```

```
foo:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        ret
bar:
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
```

Interesting this will be evaluated (`&` only):

```
int *bar(int * volatile x)
{
    return &*x;
}
```

So it is invalidating my previous opinion

Comment: The last example is producing the same result (assembly) as it would do with `return x`, so no surprise here.

Comment: Both of these examples show the same code for `return *&x;` or `return &*x;` as [GCC generates for `return x;`](https://godbolt.org/z/qz45P6GTh), so they do not illustrate any reason for not defining them to be the same as `x` without evaluating the operators. Also the latter has a constraint violation; the return type should be `volatile int *`.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence between `x` and `&*x` is enforced by [N721](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n721.htm), which makes some code previously having UB well-defined.

IIUC when `x` is a valid lvalue or a function (not considered as an lvalue in C), `*&x` is already equivalent to `x` without any additional rule. Compilers may treat them differently, but they are free not to do this.

Even if `x` is volatile-qualified, `&x` does not perform volatile read, and only produces a pointer value of type `volatile T*` (the type itself is not volatile). And then the indirection from it itself does not form a volatile access, only using the result would, which is same to the using of the simple `x`.